# session lost after form submitted - php

Tags: javascript, php, forms, session

Everything works fine, except after I submit data,  session data disappears. I already have session start at the top of the page (in useracc-test.php) which is the userpage. In the upload.php, I don't need to put session start, because it is already link (require) in the useracc-test.php page. If I do so, put session start in upload.php, it will prompt error, session already started. I browsed everywhere on the Internet, Everything I tried didn't work for me.I realise different problems require different approaches. Some people have the same problem, but the method to solve each problem is not the same as I read all  through various cases on the net. I'm stuck with this several days. It's really banging my head. pls help.tq. Any help would be very appreciated.

Below is the userpage (useracc-test.php) after the user log in.

```
<?php
//useracc-test.php
//start session
session_start();
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors",1);
//run the db connection
require 'connect-test.php';
//run the upload images etc script
require 'upload.php';

//if true, execute below
if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    //define variable
    $userName = $_POST['username'];

    //fetch data from table users
    $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();

    // place in session to echo in html later
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];

//*******************************************************   

 //create session for id field
  $id=($_SESSION['id']);

  //joined table- fetch all rows based on same id in child table useradvert  
 $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id
 WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $res2 = $stmt->get_result(); 
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="TabbedPanelsContent">

  <?php
  //display record from table- users (parent table)
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>
</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form2" 
      action="useracc-test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>category</td>
      <td><select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
        <option value="useracc-test.php" selected>Category</option>
        <option value="useracc-test.php">Members</option>
        <option value="useracc-test2-jumpmenu.php">Non-members</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td><input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Color</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="color2" id="color2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hobby</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>male
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio" value="male">
        female
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio2" value="female"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Image2</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="image2" id="image2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div align="center"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>


<ul>
  <?php
if (isset($res2)){
while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
    echo $_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
    echo $_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
    echo $_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
    echo $_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
    echo  $_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
    echo $_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];}
}
?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
</body>
</html>
```

this part below disappears when i press submit

```
 $id = isset($_POST['id']);
    $name2 = isset($_POST['name2']);
    $color2 = isset($_POST['color2']);
    $hobby2 = isset($_POST['hobby2']);
    $radiobtn = isset($_POST['radiobtn']);
    $image = isset($_FILES['image']);
    $image2 = isset($_FILES['image2']);
```

below is the upload.php page which runs the uploading script.

```
<?php
//echo var_dump($_POST);
//echo var_dump($_FILES);
require 'connect-test.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    //define variable 
   $id = $_POST['id'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$hobby2 = $_POST['hobby2'];
$radiobtn = $_POST['radiobtn'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];
$image2 = $_FILES['image2'];
    //target file for image
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//target file2 for image2
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image2"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType2 = pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//script for targetfile -image
    // Check if image or not        
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
//script for targetfile2 -image2
    // Check if image or not        
    $check2 = getimagesize($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check2 !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check2["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file2)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image2"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType2 != "jpg" && $imageFileType2 != "png" && $imageFileType2 != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType2 != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image2"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
//insert record
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2,radiobtn,image,image2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$target_file,$target_file2);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean (true or false), so in the following code: `$id = isset($_POST['id']);`,  `$id`  will either equal true or false. It will never be anything else. If you want to set the value of id to the contents of `$_POST['id']` then the code would be `$id = $_POST['id']`.

Comment: @Steve..tq for the reply..I tried that, but the problem still persist..:-(

Comment: Please clarify whats not working for you - you suggest that some `session` data gets lost/overwritten, but dont actually mention what that data is. You say `The part below disappears...` but the code that follows does not show any `session` data at all, just an attempt to access `post` data. I have pointed out the issue with that in my first comment

Comment: i even tried to redeclare $id = isset($_POST['id']); in sessions. but still the same problem.

Comment: @steve.. oh sorry steve for that. I'll pull that down. the one that doesn't disappears.. silly me.. sorry.. it's due to my lack of sleep..

Comment: Anyone out there care to help? I'm really desperate...

Comment: Is it probably because of my login form? In the Action Method, I use "?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);". After I login, the url will show "http://localhost/testing/TMP12nnttp.php". When I press submit, the url changes to" http://localhost/testing/useracc-test.php". Because in the login page. i have 'require' another page which is "connect-run.php"  which will run the login script. And in there, there is an include 'useracc-test.php" with an exit() after that.Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: I never expected this problem to be extremely difficult. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem already. To those who are 100% not using cookies like me, when the session is lost, the solution is to re-declare the variables(which is mostly parts of certain scripts). re-declare on the same page. It's actually nothing to do with header and exit, or white lines, I have studied this in depth more than a month. I have totally disabled cookies on all my terminals and remote terminals, it works 100% fine with or without cookies. Last but no least, you must define  a session id, and have start session above the page. that's all.  Nothing to do with headers, exit or white lines. (This method is only suitable for those not using cookies - however is works fine in both). Cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

> $id=($_SESSION['id']);

I am not sure why you write your code like this. Putting parentheses around a variable force to return the value vs the reference, but it matters only for the return statement, i.e.  return $var vs return ($var)

```
<?php
$q=1 ;
$r=$q;
$q=2;
echo $r, "\n"; // prints 1
$t =&$q ;
$q=3;
echo $t, "\n"; // prints 3
```

Second, I guess you mean that the value disappears from your database? Because you do this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2,radiobtn,image,image2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("issssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$target_file,$target_file2);
```

But your code above does the following

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']);
$name2 = isset($_POST['name2']);
$color2 = isset($_POST['color2']);
$hobby2 = isset($_POST['hobby2']);
$radiobtn = isset($_POST['radiobtn']);
$image = isset($_FILES['image']);
$image2 = isset($_FILES['image2']);
```

isset() will return true or false, not the value. So when you end-up to bind_param(), you bind with true/false vs the values
You should better to this

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : <a default value> ;
etc...
```

Last “In the upload.php, I don't need to put session start, because it is already link (require) in the useracc-test.php page.”: this is true only if you are not calling that script directly.

For ml2_1jzsinglecam
Here is a [link to the code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64897450/stackoverflow-347199594758417.rar) I used to test

Comment: thanks for the help..I appreciate it. About the session start, I did tried to put it in the upload.php, but whenever I tried that, it prompts error "session already started". And second, the data does not disappears from the database, the data just disappears from the browser, after I press submit.

Comment: i tried your suggestion above. But now I have an error "Notice: Undefined variable: target_dir in....... on line 63"  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

Comment: The problem still persist. Everything is working fine, except when i press the submit button, all the records which were displayed disappears. But, I have no problems inserting data. To make it clear, everytime it redirects or submit form, session data disappears.

Comment: Is it probably because of my login form? In the Action Method, I use "?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);". After I login, the url will show "http://localhost/testing/TMP12nnttp.php". When I press submit, the url changes to" http://localhost/testing/useracc-test.php". Because in the login page. i have 'require' another page which is "connect-run.php"  which will run the login script. And in there, there is an include 'useracc-test.php" with an exit() after that.Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: maybe, because I just tested your code and after couple of minors edits to get it working on my machine, the session data is working fine. I can send you my edits which I used for testing if you want to.

Comment: Yes,please. Please do. The answer is very important to be shared to all the people around the world whom are facing the same problem. Pls.tq.

Comment: Please share your answers here, so it can be accepted and be shared amongst millions of people.tq

Comment: Hi, @cyrille. I still  can't see your answer?

Comment: Why are you posting the link which redirects to the same previous answer you posted?. Doesn't make any difference. I tried that already. still same problem.

Comment: not sure what you're asking here then? please let me know

Comment: You said you posted the answer. But you only gave this link-->stackoverflow.com/a/34719959/4758417  which redirects to the same answer above which give errors. I don't see the answer above solving the problem. Maybe you can make it more clear ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to your modified code I used to test the session part. hops it helps